# Change link color (when active) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to change the color of the links in my navbar when they are active. So basically if I'm on the "about", I'd like the "about" link in my nav to have a different color than the other links. Also, I'm using Bootstrap 4.2.1.

To do that, I made this :

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg container-fluid" id="navbar-main">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="container navbar-nav justify-content-around">
      <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../sections/index.php"><span>Accueil</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="../sections/presentation.php" class="nav-link navigation" ><span>Présentation</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/historique.php"><span>Historique</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/photos.php"><span>Photos des chats</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a>
          </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Elena_/mwztr37y/4/

But the color doesn't change or when it works, the links are somehow dead (I click on them but the page doesn't change).

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thank for your help !

Comment: You want to add the class `active` to whatever page nav item you are currently on. Also you want to use a style like `nav-pills` or `nav-tabs` otherwise `active` provides no styling. ex: https://jsfiddle.net/97dL53n6/ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Well thanks, it does work now but my links are still dead, I can't change the page by clicking on them. That's the first time this is happening to me, I don't understand the problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that is working exactly like I wanted to so I wanted to share it ! :)

```
jQuery(function($) {
         var path = window.location.href;
         $('li a').each(function() {
          if (this.href === path) {
           $(this).addClass('active');
          }
         });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your CSS was targeting the a tag but the script was referencing the li tag.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".navbar .nav-item.active .nav-link").click(function () {
        
       $(".navbar .nav-item.active .nav-link").removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
       return false;
   });
  });
```

```css
.navbar {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #F7E4E8;

}
.navbar a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}
.navbar .active {
 color: #0CF;
}
.navbar a {
    color: black;
}

.selected {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg container-fluid" id="navbar-main">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="container navbar-nav justify-content-around">
      <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../sections/index.php"><span>Accueil</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="../sections/presentation.php" class="nav-link navigation" ><span>Présentation</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/historique.php"><span>Historique</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/photos.php"><span>Photos</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link navigation" href="../sections/contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a>
          </li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".navbar .nav-item.active .nav-link").click(function () {
        
       $(".navbar .nav-item.active .nav-link").removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
       return false;
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was not working but nevermind, I found a solution :)